# How do I write private set auto-properties in VB 10?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, automatic-properties

in C#:

```
public string Property { get; private set; }
```

in VB?

[Please vote or/and share your ideas!](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=465539)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that is possible (yet).

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589(VS.100).aspx) on MSDN.
The above article even links to [another one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01143ea4(VS.100).aspx) about mixed access levels.

I found [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=457176) on Microsoft Connect, so they are thinking about it (If it will be for VS2010 that's another question).

Comment: Would love to hear how the new mixed access level auto-props will look!

Comment: If you read both articles you'll see that mixed access level auto properties will not be available in VS2010

Comment: In the last link you posted they're talking about a ReadOnly property this is a property 'without' a Set not a Private Set. So still no mixed access level auto properties in vs2010.

Comment: Isn't a readonly property in vb equivalent with a private set in C#? You have to be able to set the variable somewhere, don't you? And as we're talking about auto-properties, being properties without a private backing field (or rather "with one that's generated on the fly").

Comment: You do have to set the variable somwhere but the equivalent of a readonly property in c# is public string Property { get; } Which is impossible as it will be in vb. In the current vb autoprop syntaxt it is afaics impossible to make a private or internal set. If you read the article at your last post and see the proposed solution you'll see it's as I say.

Comment: are you freakin kidding me?  no auto properties in VB?  This is another example of why I HATE VB.NET with a passion

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: Eurm... auto properties do actually exist in VB (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx). We're talking about auto properties with private set here...

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
Private Thingy As Integer
Property Thing() As Integer
    Get
        Return Thingy
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Thingy = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Auto property in VB10

```
Property PartNo As Integer = 44302
```

But with a private set still can't be done in vb not even in VB10 see here:

From MSDN (as john said):

> Property Definitions That Require
>   Standard Syntax :
>
> - Specify different accessibility for
>     the Get and Set procedure. For
>     example, you might want to make the
>     Set procedure Private and the Get
>     procedure Public.

Comment: Shimmy is referring to automatic properties... I don't think this is one.

Comment: How do I write private set *auto-properties* in VB 10?

Comment: @Shimmy, ask that as a question on itself and you are more likely to receive a proper response

Answer (score 5):

According to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd293589(VS.100).aspx), you can't:

> Auto-implemented properties are
>   convenient and support many
>   programming scenarios. However, there
>   are situations in which you cannot use
>   an auto-implemented property and must
>   instead use standard, or expanded,
>   property syntax.
>
> You have to use expanded
>   property-definition syntax if you want
>   to do any one of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - Specify different accessibility for
>     the Get and Set procedure. For
>     example, you might want to make the
>     Set procedure Private and the Get
>     procedure Public.