# VB.net automatic properties with different access level for set

Tags: vb.net, automatic-properties

In c# you can auto property a value with different level of access for the get and set . . . e.g.

```
public String myString
{
  get;
  private set;
}
```

Is there away to do that with automatic properties in vb.net or are you forced to go for the long winded implementation of properties?

e.g. I don't want to do this all the time

```
Dim _myString As String
Public Property MyString() As String
  Get
    Return _myString
  End Get
  Private Set(ByVal value As String)
    _myString = value
  End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Don't you have a nice snippet to take care of that for you?

Comment: well . . . I guess I could do that I was mostly interested if there was any language support for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968971/how-do-i-write-private-set-auto-properties-in-vb-10/969028#969028), you can't.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it's in VB.NET 2010 either.  You can do this:

```
Public Property myProp As String = "Foo"
```

(This will give you a public getter and setter.)

But you can't set different levels of access.  You would still have to manually implement them.